# Can you load elements in a nested json into multiple rows in Big Query from Kafka using Kafka Connect and Big Query Sink?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking to see if Kafka Connect is a possible solution for my use case. I need to write from Kafka into a Big Query Dataset in near real time. My message contains multiple nested elements which needs to be written into multiple rows. An example is below

```
  "header": {
    "head1": "example",
    "head2": "",
    "head3": "",
    "version": "v1.0",
    "timestamp": "2022-04-29 10:02:17+0000"
  },
  "message": {
    "field1": "example",
    "field2": "2022-04-29 08:25:36+0000",
    "list": [{
      "listfield1": "listexample1",
      "listfield2": "listexample1",
      "listfield3": "listexample1"
    },
      {
        "listfield1": "listexample2",
        "listfield2": "listexample2",
        "listfield3": "listexample2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So in this example there are two nested messages in the list. Each one needs to be its own row in the Big Query table with the other fields all being loaded as well so example the end result in Big Query would look something like

|field1 |field2|listfield1|listfield2|listfield3|
|:------|:-----|----------|----------|---------|
|example|2022-04-29 08:25:36+0000|listexample1|listexample1|listexample1
|example|2022-04-29 08:25:36+0000|listexample2|listexample2|listexample2
Is this possible with the Kafka Connect functionality or will the message need to be transformed prior to or post being fed through Kafka connect?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

In order to write multiple rows, you'll need to split the data into individual records on your own; Connect cannot do this via transforms